# C : printf changes course of program

Tags: opengl, timer, printf, glut, glui

I've got a program that simulates collisions (circles) using openGL, GLUT, GLUI. Everything worked fine but when I changed my code a bit it began to do weird things.

I have 2 buttons, "play" and "step", "play" simulates the collisions updated with a timer, "step" also simulates but you've got to click it in order to go further.

Originally it did that but now the "play" button acts the same as "step". If I add a printf in my timer callback it all works perfectly...

What can I do ?

In my timer_cb I only have got :

```
 // printf("something\n");
 glutPostRedisplay();
 glutTimerFunc(getDeltaT(), timer_cb, 0);
```

Comment: Missing curly braces around if ?

Comment: You've not shown enough information for anyone to do more than speculate what the problem is. Possibly you have undefined behaviour which unluckily for you the `printf` hides. As @H2CO3 says it might be an accidental inclusion/exclusion from an if/else/do/while/for. To ask a good question you need a *minimal* yet still complete amount of code that conclusively and unambiguously illustrates the exact problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

The I/O routines, like printf, introduce a sensible delay by calling them. To answer with a certain degree of correctness you show us the User Interface code, but I think I can guess...

Are you using threads? Maybe it can be a concurrency bug because the execution of the button event handler is not synchronized with the update logic?